# Creating python list of feature classes or layers using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers, feature-class, list

Step 1: I will generate a series of point feature classes. Each will have half the distance between points as its predecessor.

Step 2: I then want to cycle over those point feature classes, but in reverse.

Can I create a list of feature classes or layers as I go in step 1, so I can reverse through it in step 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is not entirely clear about what you need help with, I'm assuming you know how to halve the distance between points of the predecessing feature class.

You could simply create an empty list of feature classes by declaring the variable.

```
fcList = []

<enter your code here for generating your feature classes>
```

As you create a feature class, fc, add it to the list.

```
fcList.append(fc)
```

You can reverse the list by:

```
fcList.reverse()
```

Cycle through your list using a for loop:

```
for fc in fcList:
    do something...
```

Or, you can take your original list and cycle through it backwards this way:

```
for fc in reversed(fcList):
    do something...
```

Comment: Thanks. Ignore me. The Workspace variable was playing up and generated an odd set of names but after a restart it works fine.